# inserting popup window command in sql

Tags: javascript, php

I'm assigning popup window on my links but it doesn't work sorry i'm still learning about mysqli and javascript.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
 $id = $row['BapID'];
echo "<tr>";
 echo "<th>" . "<a href=bapview.php?BapID=$id onlick='pop_up(this);'>View Full Info</a>" .
            "&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;" .
        "<a href=bapupdate.php?BapID=$id onlick='pop_up(this);'>Edit</a>" .  "</th>";
```

My script

```
function pop_up(url){
window.open(url,'win2','status=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,titlebar=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,width=1076,height=768,directories=no,location=no') }
```

Comment: You need to make sure that you spell things correctly, such as `onclick` instead of the `onlick` that you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url that you want the pop-up window to point should be put as the parameter to your function call in your onclick handlers:

```
<a onclick="pop_up('bapupdate.php?<?php echo $id; ?>');">Edit</a>
```

As you can see at

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open

the first parameter to the window.open method is a string value for the url you want the opening window to point to. Your code was attempting to provide as that argument the actual reference to the `link` element on your page (that's what `this` will refer to in that context).

Comment: Thank you for your reply
but the code that you have given is giving me a
    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' 
maybe because this is inside the mysqli?

Comment: It's because of his bad style of opening and breaking tags and not posting it as you have it. All you have to do is move your href inside your popup call, minus the 'href=' of course

Comment: @ElefantPhace Thanks for the call-out there, but let me clarify: I wanted to remove the thought process from the situation. This way, the OP would have an example of what the argument might look like, rather than simply cutting and pasting my answer into his code and continuing on.

Comment: @myesain I'm guilty for that sorry, Thank you ......................................................................................                    

ElefantPhace: Thank you

Comment: @user1889618 Hey man, I just hope you learn something here. That's why were all here. Keep it up.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions:

1. Don't be afraid to 'exit' (?>) PHP half way through a script. This will make it easier to read later on and allows you to write in pure HTML.
2. It looks like your missing you quotation marks around your href parameter. This likely won't cause issues but you never know. I would also recommend using the full url in your href and also as your pop_up() parameter (as suggested by @myesain)

   ```
   <?php
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
      $id = $row['BapID']; ?>
      <tr>
        <th>
           <a href=# onclick='pop_up("http://fullurl.com/bapview.php?BapID=<?php echo $id; ?>");'>View Full Info</a>
           &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
           <a href=# onclick='pop_up"http://fullurl.com/bapupdate.php?BapID=<?php echo $id; ?>");'>Edit</a>
        </th>
      </tr>
   <?php
      //Rest of code
   ?>
   ```

Comment: I tried that in the past it only gives me an error, but thanks a lot for the suggestion.

Comment: unexpected end of the file which is </html>
in using ?> halfway

Comment: Remember to use the `;` symbol to end your lines of code in PHP, it's good practice to do this even if the is only one line of code. e.g `<?php echo $some_var; ?>`

Comment: Why have you not fixed your answer yet?

Comment: @ElefantPhace I already fixed it. I was just asking for his 1st suggestion about using the closing tag ?>.

Comment: @MichaelSmith yeah that was my problem ";" thank you.

Comment: there, I fixed it for you.